# Doctrine 2: Load entity and childs count

Tags: php, count, doctrine-orm

I have these two entities:

**Message entity**

```
class Message
{
    /**
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
    * @JoinColumn(name="author", referencedColumnName="id_user")
    */
    protected $author;
```

**User entity**

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false, name="id_user")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;
```

I need to get the total of messages of user and its data in order to  *echo* something like this:

```
echo $user->getName() . " have {$user->totalOfMessage()}";
```

I now that I can make a relation in User entity to get a message collection. But I don't know if it necessary only to get the size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found the answer. At least one good option.

As of Doctrine 2.1 you can mark associations as extra lazy. This means that calling $user->getMessages()->count() won't load the messages, it will just issue a COUNT query to the database.

You can read about extra lazy collections here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

Comment: correct according to the documentation, but I could not make it working

Comment: @Elvis, try to post your entities to take a look

Comment: I managed to make it working, I wasn't putting the `fetch: EXTRA_LAZY` under the join column. I could not find clear related documentation

Comment: `fetch: EXTRA_LAZY` is only supported for `Doctrine +2.1`: [Extra Lazy Associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've recently been trying to get the EXTRA_LAZY loading working and found what I think is quite a major mistake in the documentation as shown on page:-

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

I expect that most Doctrine users may realise that the fetch="EXTRA_LAZY" needs to be put on the 'owning' side of the ManyToMany relationship but the example shows the annotation being added to a line which contains 'mappedBy' which is NOT the owning side?

By adding the fetch="EXTRA_LAZY" directive to the non-owning side it gets completely ignored as I now know it should be. I think this should be more clearly stated in the documentation.

I could not find any article anywhere explaining this after exhaustive searching so I'd say this is probably worth an amendment to the docs?

In our use case it's made a particularly intensive block of processing which used quite a number of 'contains' calls and which constantly crashed due to exceeding memory limits into a quick process which now executes orders of magnitude faster.

Hope this info helps someone out there...